# Passar mouse sobre div e abrir maior

Tags: jquery, html, css, css3

Desejo que, ao passar o mouse sobre uma `div`, essa mesma `div` seja ampliada, tal como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma lista com vários elementos, quando passar o mouse sobre o elemento (`div`), ela ficaria por cima bem no centro e abriria um efeito (talvez transition do css3).

Alguma dica?

Comment: Ampla demais ? Quem falou isso ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assim você se refere ?

```css
div.content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 880px;
}
div.blocos {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #C7C7C7;
  position: relative;
}

div.o{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}
div.blocos:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color: #000;
}
div.blocos:hover div.o{
  transform: scale(1.8);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="blocos">
  <div class="o"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocos">
<div class="o"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocos">
<div class="o"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocos">
<div class="o"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocos">
<div class="o"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sim, porém, abriria outra div com esse efeito, não aumentaria a mesma. 
Preciso de outro conteúdo dentro desta div que vai abrir, e ela teria que ficar por cima de todas as outras.

Comment: Editei o post. Veja se te atende

Comment: Valeu @TobyMosque... Havia esquecido do efeito.

Comment: @Zoom, adicionei o vendor prefix `-webkit-` para o `transform`

Comment: @Zoom, o AP não pediu por efeito, apenas acho estranho este tipo de animação sem ;D

Comment: Eu vi @TobyMosque, acrescentei mais dois e unifiquei o `transition` em uma só linha

Comment: Pediu sim, aqui: **abriria com um efeito, talvez transition do css3.**...

Comment: Isso mesmo, apenas adicionei um visibility hidden quando o mouse não está em cima, e adicionei um visibility visible quando passar o mouse, vou testar!! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @LucasHenriqueDutra acho que `opacity: 0` e `opacity: 1` fica mais profissional do que usar `visibility`.

Comment: Vou utilizar, eu tinha usado visibility porque li em algum forum que eu conseguiria usar algum efeito com transition, mas assim está ótimo.
Obrigado @Zoom !!